# Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ̂ (U+302)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. ... $\widehat{\left (OA,AA' \right )}$

Tags: accents, input-encodings

I'm writing my dissertation in Portuguese but the latex is finding this kind of error. In fact, I'm using some mathematical characters. How do I resolve this? Here below is the location of the error in the latex source code. Thank you

```
Sendo que as tensões de entrada $U_{OA}$ e a de saída $U_{OA'}$ são constantes e iguais e o ângulo projetado entre essas tensões é igual a $7,5^{\circ}$, então deduz que os ângulos $\widehat{\left (OA,AA' \right )}$ e ̂$\widehat{\left ( AA,A'O \right )}$ são iguais a  $86,25^{\circ}$, mostrado na figura \ref{diagramafasauto}. Note-se que Co representa a extensão de C (fase c) e OCo a bissetriz do ângulo $\widehat{\left ( OA,AB \right )}$, então o valor do ângulo  $\widehat{\left ( OA,OCo \right )}$ é igual a $60^{\circ}$. Deduz-se então o ângulo  $\widehat{\left ( OA',OCo \right )}$.
```

Comment: `â` should be input as a single character U+00E2 and not as the combination `a`+U+0302 (combining circumflex accent).

Answer (score 2):

In the following part of your input,

> então deduz que os ângulos $\widehat{\left (OA,AA' \right )}$ e ̂$\widehat{\left ( AA,A'O \right )}$ são iguais

specifically this part:

> )}$ e ̂$\widehat

the sequence of Unicode characters between the dollar signs (inclusive) is:

```
‎U+0024  DOLLAR SIGN
‎U+0020  SPACE
‎U+0065  LATIN SMALL LETTER E
‎U+0020  SPACE
‎U+0302  COMBINING CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT
‎U+0024  DOLLAR SIGN
```

You may not be able to see it in your editor or here, but if you copy and paste it into a Unicode character viewer like [this one](https://r12a.github.io/uniview/), you will be able to see it.

That [U+0302 COMBINING CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT](https://codepoints.net/U+0302) is meaningless there, and you probably don't want it. What you want there between (strictly) the dollar signs is probably just `e`. With just this change to your input, it works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

Sendo que as tensões de entrada $U_{OA}$ e a de saída $U_{OA'}$ são constantes e iguais e o ângulo projetado entre essas tensões é igual a $7,5^{\circ}$, então deduz que os ângulos $\widehat{\left (OA,AA' \right )}$ e $\widehat{\left ( AA,A'O \right )}$ são iguais a  $86,25^{\circ}$, mostrado na figura \ref{diagramafasauto}. Note-se que Co representa a extensão de C (fase c) e OCo a bissetriz do ângulo $\widehat{\left ( OA,AB \right )}$, então o valor do ângulo  $\widehat{\left ( OA,OCo \right )}$ é igual a $60^{\circ}$. Deduz-se então o ângulo  $\widehat{\left ( OA',OCo \right )}$.

\end{document}
```

producing:

[image: typeset output]

---

That solves the problem, but note that without the fix, TeX actually tells you everything you need to know, pointing out the exact character at which there is a problem:

```
l.5 ...los $\widehat{\left (OA,AA' \right )}$ e ̂
                                                  $\widehat{\left ( AA,A'O \...
```

— the top line is everything that was read before the error happened, and the bottom line is what is not yet read.

A word of advice: you can avoid such super-long lines in your input. TeX (by default) treats a single newline character as equivalent to a space, so you may have an easier time debugging errors (if you don't take time to learn the error-line format) if you have shorter lines. (Of course, long lines are not a problem if you know how to deal with them.)